# Using git to manage virtualenv state: will this cause problems?

Tags: python, git, virtualenv

I currently have git and virtualenv set up in a way which exactly
suits my needs and, so far, hasn't caused any problems. However I'm aware that
my setup is non-standard and I'm wondering if anyone more familiar with virtualenv's
internals can point out if, and where, it's likely to go wrong.

#### My setup

My virtualenv is inside my git repository, but git is set to ignore the `bin` and `include` directories and everything in `lib` *except* for the `site-packages` directory.

More precisely, my `.gitignore` file looks like this:

```
*.pyc

# Ignore all the virtualenv stuff except the actual packages
# themselves
/bin
/include
/lib/python*/*
!/lib/python*/site-packages

# Ignore easyinstall and setuptools
/lib/python*/site-packages/easy-install.pth
/lib/python*/site-packages/setuptools.pth
/lib/python*/site-packages/setuptools-*
/lib/python*/site-packages/pip-*
```

With this arrangement I -- and anyone else working on a checkout of the project -- can use virtualenv and pip as normal but with the following advantages:

1. If anyone updates or installs a package and pushes their changes, anyone else who pulls those changes automatically gets the update: they don't need to notice that a `requirements.txt` file has changed or do any `post-receive` hook magic.
2. There are no network dependencies: all the code to make the application work lives in the git repository.

I'm aware that this only works with pure-Python packages, but that's all I'm concerned with at the moment.

Does anyone know of any other problems with this approach that I should be aware of?

Comment: Dear googler, also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9586346/82216

Comment: +1 for putting your .gitignore out there for my copy-paste

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have any `-e` items in your `requirements.txt` - in other words if you have any editable dependencies as described in the [format](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirement-format.html) that are using the `git` version control system you will most likely run into issues when your `src` directory is committed. If you just add `/src` to your `.gitignore` then you can avoid this problem, but often the installation just adds a pointer in `site-packages` to this location, so you need it!

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks. I can see that this might be problematic. I'll have to go and experiment.

Answer (score 10):

This is an interesting question. I think the other two answers (thus far) raise good specific points. Clearly you've thought this through and have arrived at a solution you like, but I'll note that there does seem to be a philosophical split here among virtualenv users.

One camp, to which I'd guess you belong, feels that the local VE is part of the project (i.e. it should be under version control). The other feels that the VE should essentially be treated as a development artifact -- that requirements.txt should be part of the project repo, but that you should be able to blow away and recreate the VE as needed.

I just mention this because when I first saw this distinction made, it helped shape my thinking about virtualenv. (I'm in the second camp, FWIW, because it seems simpler and cleaner to me, but that's not to say that being in the first camp is wrong for your particular project.)

Comment: Yes, you're completely right about this philosophical split. Although, obviously, the "check it all in" approach only really makes sense for projects where you fully control the runtime environment (as is the case for most web-based projects), and not for projects that are going to be run by many different users. Personally, I can see the arguments on both sides - at this stage I'm just trying to work out the practical consequences of one particular approach.

Answer (score 2):

In `/lib/python2.7/site-packages` in my virtualenv I have absolute paths, for example in `Django.egg-link` I have `/Users/henry/.virtualenv/mowapp/src/django` (this is a Mac).

Check to see if you have any absolute paths checked into git, I think that is a major problem with this approach.

Comment: Thanks for this. Absolute paths were the first thing I checked for, and so far I haven't hit any - whether this is just a fluke of the particular packages I happen to have installed I don't know. From the paths you mentioned, it looks like you're using virtualenvwrapper which I'd imagine wouldn't play nicely with my approach.