# Is it ok to publish "venv" folder of a Python project into my GIT repository?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, virtualenv

I am pretty new in Python and I have the following doubt related publishing a Python project on a GIT repository: have I to avoid to publish also the **venv** folder on my GIT repository or is it good to put also this folder into the repository?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtualenv and source version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586346/virtualenv-and-source-version-control)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you want to avoid publishing the virtual environment containing the installed dependencies for your project. The dependencies might not be cross-platform compatible.

Especially for projects that need to compile some C extensions generally each platform requires a separate binary ( or compilation).

It is more common to enumerate your dependencies in a `requirements.txt` file. The `requirements.txt` file should contain all the dependencies that are necessary to run your project.

In order not to publish your local `venv` to git, two approaches are possible:

- Keep your virtual environments in a location that is not inside the git root of your project
- Add the virtual environment to the .gitignore file

Answer (score 2):

Most projects I have seen usually put all the *venv* files in the `.gitignore`, as, to my understanding, virtual environments are unique to each machine, so if you grab a *venv* in a specific computer, it won't work in another. Instead, each machine should have its own *venv* created locally.